# Order of importance , time order and space order

Tags: grammar

Why can't I say "Importance order" while I can say "time order" or "space order".

Comment: Can you say "space order" and "time order" ?

Comment: I know what "time order" generally means. What's "space order"?

Comment: It was in a book.

Comment: Which book? Please quote and/or link the relevant part.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can say *space order* (if you *did*, I might not understand it anyway).

But people do sometimes speak of items [listed in **size** order](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22listed+in+size+order%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) or [**weight** order](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22listed%20in%20importance%20order%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22listed%20in%20weight%20order%22&tbm=bks), and quite a few of these written instances of [in **importance** order](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22in%20importance%20order%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are for the current context.

It's much, *much* more common to say [listed in [ascending/descending] **order of importance**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22listed%20in%20importance%20order%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22listed%20in%20order%20of%20importance%22&tbm=bks).

I don't think there are really any grammatical principles involved here. You can modify *order* with any abstract noun denoting a [scalar](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scalar) attribute *(capable of being represented by a point on a scale)*.

But because in practice we normally use the form *order of xxxxx*, it sounds slightly odd to use the abstract noun as an adjectival modifier. It's just a bit *less* odd if the noun is short and commonly used in such contexts.

So far as I'm concerned, nothing changes if you use *sequence* instead of *order*, or precede your noun by another modifier such as *ascending/descending* (which is often necessary for clarity).

---

In general, whatever specific "xxxx = adjectival abstract noun" we look at, *order of xxxx* is far more common than *xxxx order*. Except possibly time, which is unique in that it's the only "property" that actually has a built-in concept of scalar "direction" (c.f. [time's arrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_of_time)).

Comment: There are quite a few links available for 'space order' - for example http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/encomium/writingdemo/wb/wt/wt_08_b.htm Common to all these is using the term as adjective to the noun form of order.

Comment: @user49727: Presumably *in context*, those who've written that assume the meaning is comprehensible. I haven't looked, but I guess they probably mean ***capacity***, since I don't know how else to interpret "scalar" ***space***.

Comment: no - they are using it as an alternative to 'spatial'

Comment: @user49727: Okay, I've just looked at your link. I think that particular usage is bordering on nonsense (*spatial, height, position* or *location*, for example, would be at least "credible" there).

Comment: I'm hardly inclined to defend their particular preference for this usage. I was simply responding to your own legimitization of 'Importance' based on an instance, which I have to say is definitely nonsensical. The very fact that they have to explain what they mean by 'importance order' says it all. And the explanation as it turns out is not particularly clever.

Comment: @user49727: I think that's a bit glib. Only one of the two *importance order* citations defines the usage, and it's worth noting there are many more relevant instances of [listed by importance](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22listed+by+importance%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but hardly any [listed by space](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22listed+by+space%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22listed+by+space%22&start=10&tbm=bks). That's because you can say *this is **more important** than that*, but you can't really say *this is **more space** than that* in a "scalar" sense.

Comment: The cases you cite that are using "importance order" are both scientific manuscripts written by non-native speakers. One is a Spanish and the other a German speaker so I don't think we can draw any conclusions as to the usage of this phrase in English.

Comment: @terdon: Well, as I hope both the text and the links in my answer show, *none* of these usages are exactly "normal". Whatever specific "xxxx = adjectival abstract noun" we look at, *order of xxxx* totally swamps *xxxx order*. Except possibly ***time***, which is unique in that it's the only "property" that actually has a built-in concept of scalar progression ([time's arrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_of_time), and all that).

Comment: Yes of course, your main point is that "order _of_ importance_ is much more common than _in importance order_, I am just highlighting the fact by pointing out that you only found two references for the former and both were from non-native speakers.

Comment: @terdon: Point taken. I've amended the link, which I'm quite confident will now include at least a few examples from [contrary] native speakers.

Comment: Heh, nope, you've still not satisfied this pedant. All cases listed are either from non-natives (based on their name at least) or quoting non natives (Respiration Disorders, quoting A. Bruwier and colleagues from a French publication) or instances of "... importance, order, ...". Stop fighting me, I'm proving your point :).

Comment: @terdon: Do not cross [s]words with *me*, young sirrah! :) Corbin M. Wright may not be a world-famous author, but just glancing at the text around [relate those 5 talents mentioned above to your job search by writing them **in importance order** under your goal](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22writing+them+in+importance+order+under%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) suggests that he's a native speaker with perfectly good command of written English (seriously, thanks for proving my point! :)

Comment: No fair! You went on to the second page of results!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the first is always a noun, whereas the other two can be used as adjectives.

Unless you are describing two concrete objects it is unusual to have two consecutive nouns in a sentence.

In all these cases ***order*** is the noun and *time*, *space* are used in their adjective sense to qualify *order*. *Importance* cannot be used as it is always a noun and the adjective form would not carry the intended meaning.

Comment: *Time, space* and *importance* are all nouns, used attributively to modify another noun. *Space* is not an adjective.

Comment: Noun used attributively is an adjective. And you cannot use 'importance' attributively.